# Return null in ResponseEntity body (Spring Boot RESTful)

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, spring-boot

I'm creating a RESTFul Web Service with the following service available:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<GenericModel>> returnEmpty() {
    List<GenericModel> genericModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    return responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(genericModelList, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When the empty list returns, I'm getting the following response in browser:

```
[]
```

How can I do to receive in browser a "null" response instead of []? There's some way to tell Spring to render my list size 0 as "null" and not as []?

Comment: why not initialize it to `null`?

Comment: If it's supposed to be a list, why not return the empty list instead? That doesn't require special-casing by your clients.

Comment: Sorry by confusion. What I want is return a "null" in response body. If I do this:  return new ResponseEntity<>(null, headers, HttpStatus.OK) the browser shows a blank page, I want to show "null".

Answer (score 3):

One way of pivoting it based on if the `genericModelList` is empty of not could be:-

```
if(genericModelList.isEmpty()) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
} else {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(genericModelList, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

or else you can skip the `body` using [`ResponseEntity(MultiValueMap<String,String> headers, HttpStatus status)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#ResponseEntity-org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap-org.springframework.http.HttpStatus-) constructor as well.

Comment: When I skip the body, the browser shows a blank page, no content body. I want to display a "null" in body. I'm using a JQuerey Ajax request to access this data, and I want to this to be able to compare if result == null. And if the body is blank I receive a error because is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @HélioMárcioFilho You can use the highlighted code in the answer. Skipping the body was just an alternate since I didn't knew this much about your usage prior to answering. Hence placed an ***or else*** in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you just initialize the `genericModelList` as an **empty** list, not null. Or you can check the size of list before sending response back with different body.

Comment: I do this because I can't return a null list. I already tried return a null list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, I will try to be more clear next time. I solved the problem.

I was trying to send "null" in the body of my ResponseEntity> when my List size is 0, but Jackson creates a "[]" JSON and not a "null" as I wanted. I didn't found a way to change this default Jackson's bahavior, so I decided to abandon Jackson and use the Gson library.

Let me show a example of my solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> returnEmpty() {

    List<GenericModel> genericModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    String body = "";

    if (genericModelList.size() == 0) {
        body = "null";
    } else {
        body = gson.toJson(genericModelList);
    }

    return responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This way, returning a String and parsing to JSON myself with Gson instead of use automatic parsing from Spring/Jackson, I can control the resulting JSON. Look that I explicity return a String "null" if my List.size() == 0.